# BigQuery StandardSQL udf to call external .jar libraries

Tags: google-bigquery

How do i call external java libraries in the bigquery UDF. Is it possible?

Following is my use case:
Is it possible to do the lat/long calculations inside standard sql bigquery UDF.

```
import org.gavaghan.geodesy.*;

...

GeodeticCalculator geoCalc = new GeodeticCalculator();

Ellipsoid reference = Ellipsoid.WGS84;  

GlobalPosition pointA = new GlobalPosition(latitude, longitude, 0.0); // Point A

GlobalPosition userPos = new GlobalPosition(userLat, userLon, 0.0); // Point B

double distance = geoCalc.calculateGeodeticCurve(reference, userPos, pointA).getEllipsoidalDistance();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery UDFs support *JavaScript* as the language, not Java, so it is not possible to call an external Java library. You can, however, [load external libraries with JavaScript UDFs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#including-external-libraries).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of going UDF direction, you can try BigQuery GIS (public alpha)

Based on your example - it can look something like below simplified/silly example

```
#standardSQL
WITH start AS (
    SELECT 
        state_name state,
        CAST(internal_point_lat AS FLOAT64) lat, 
        CAST(internal_point_lon AS FLOAT64) lon
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.us_states_area`
    WHERE state_name IN ('California', 'Arizona')
),  finish AS (
    SELECT 
        state_name state,
        CAST(internal_point_lat AS FLOAT64) lat, 
        CAST(internal_point_lon AS FLOAT64) lon
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.us_states_area`
    WHERE state_name IN ('Florida', 'New York')
)
SELECT 
    start.state start,
    finish.state finish,
    ROUND(ST_DISTANCE(ST_GEOGPOINT(start.lon,start.lat),ST_GEOGPOINT(finish.lon,finish.lat))*0.000621371,2) distance
FROM start, finish    

Row start       finish      distance
1   California  Florida     2223.17
2   California  New York    2331.66
3   Arizona     Florida     1761.82
4   Arizona     New York    2019.12
```

Note: BQ-GIS is in public alpha, so your GCP project will need to be whitelisted to try out these queries. You can sign up to request access [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdaf8RsWhQSvC6hnasaRhrtghmiGyDr2z0Vf97w5IDuwUlXdg/viewform) .

> Update (*based on comment*)

i see. so GIS example was just "accidental" example and not a focus of question at all. Got it. As of UDF - only JavaScript and SQL UDF are supported by BigQuery nowadays and for JS UDF external libraries supported too. java/python are out of luck so far. The only other crazy option you can check is using web assembly.
You can check few examples to get an idea:

- [BigQuery beyond SQL and JS: Running C and Rust code at scale](https://medium.com/@hoffa/bigquery-beyond-sql-and-js-running-c-and-rust-code-at-scale-33021763ee1f)
- [Calling c functions from bigquery with web assembly](https://blog.sourced.tech/post/calling-c-functions-from-bigquery/)

Comment: Thank you Mikhail. My question was generic about calling external .jar files. Basically we are migrating from Hadoop to Bigquery. We are in the process of converting our HiveQL scripts to BQScripts. We have hive UDFs which reference java/python libraries. How can i get the same functionality in Big Query.